# Why can I access Object's method via an Interface that doesn't define them?

Tags: java

Given the following interface and implementation class:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public String getSomething ();
}

public class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

   @Override
   public String getSomething () {
      return "Someting";
   } 

   public String getOtherThing () {
      return "otherThing";
   }
}
```

And then some client code:

```
MyInterface objectViaMyInt = new MyImplementation();

objectViaMyInt.getSometing();   //WORKS, OF COURSE
objectViaMyInt.getOtherThing(); //DOESNT WORK, OF COURSE
objectViaMyInt.toString();      // WORKS TOO
```

So, I think I understand the spirit of this . .. every object is an Object and should inherit those essential methods.  But how does this actually work?  It seems that it can't follow the normal rules for inheritance and interface ( type ) based access . . .

Comment: Because an interface can't normally inherit from an Class, correct?  My implementation class inherits from object, but what rule allows filtering through of the object methods but not the impl specific ones.

Comment: BTW, I know this is a duplicate, but the other questions weren't clearly enough written for an important question like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But how does this actually work?

At a language level, it works because [JLS section 9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2) says it does:

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

At a JVM level, the JVM can just use the knowledge that every instance of an interface must obviously be an object, so it can get at the right member implementations in the normal way.

Comment: +1 How are you able to find where exactly any paragraph is in such a large JLS, that too so fast? :)

Comment: The specification has spoken!!  I should have known that.

Comment: @Rohit Jain  I think he's got a resident search index to it in his brain.

Comment: @RohitJain: It doesn't take long to search for the chapter on interfaces, then find the "members" section...

Comment: @RohitJain Bookmark [js7spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)  hit CTRL/CMD+F